# Leakcanary showing AdActivity leaked

Tags: android, memory-leaks, admob, leakcanary

I was using **LeakCanary** for checking memory leaks. I also integrated google **admob** in my app. But LeakCanary is showing memory leaks in `AdActivity` which is not part of my app, it's provided by admob. Do I need to concern with those leaks? It's also showing possible leak for **FirebaseInAppMessaging**.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the provided leaktrace, it looks like FirebaseInAppMessagingDisplay is causing the leak (it doesn't really matter which activity is leaking). You should file a bug against the firebase in app messaging library, and provide them with the string representation of the leak (overflow menu => share).